# Javascript - Script and Module Records

Tags: javascript, module, record

[Script Record](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#table-script-records) has [[LoadedModules]] field which is confusing since the script record is not even part of the initial execution context when a script of type module is evaluated. ScriptOrModule component of the initial [Execution Context](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#table-state-components-for-all-execution-contexts) points to [Module Record](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#table-module-record-fields). Or am I wrong?

Comment: "*the script record is not even part of the initial execution context when a script of type module is evaluated*" - a module is not a script.

Comment: That's my point. A script is not a module yet the Script Record has [[LoadedModules]] field. why?

Comment: Because it still might use dynamic `import()`

Comment: Thank you. You taught me something today. I didn't know it was possible to use dynamic import within a script. I always used it whitin a module.